# Can we upgrage only rxjs version and keeping everything else on the same version

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on Angular 4 project and Now I need to use one of [WebSocket package](https://github.com/ohjames/rxjs-websockets) but it throws following errors after `npm install` to upgrade rxjs version and when I try to upgrade only rxjs version and run `ng-serve` it throws exceptions and many errors.

```
npm WARN queueing-subject@0.3.0 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN rxjs-websockets@6.0.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^6.1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Currently, I am having **rxjs:^5.1.0** in *package.json* and when I tried to upgrade only rxjs version it throws various errors.

> ng-v

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 4.4.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualy there is a library that allows you to validly refer to the old rxjs 5 version operators  while using version 6. It is called [rxjs-compat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs-compat).
But be carefull, it increases the bundle size of your application and it should be considered only as temporary solution.

Consider this part of [migration guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#user-content-backwards-compatibility)

And the solution seems to look like this:

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight and link. yes it is written that "This size increase is exacerbated if you are using a version of Webpack before 4.0.0." and we are having webpack 3.11. better to drop idea to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can by running this command

```
 npm install -g rxjs@6
```

or this

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

rxjs-compat provides a compatibility layer between the v6 and v5 APIs

read more about it here

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration